# Pass variable from JavascriptExecutor to Java Variable

Tags: java, selenium

Hello i am using Selenium with Java ,  trying to convert JavascriptExecutor inside script var to Java String . 
actually i have written a js method to get clicked element. I am trying to fetch clicked element's attribute .

Here is my Code :

```
    js.executeScript("document.body.addEventListener(\"click\", function (evt) {\n"
                    + "    console.dir(this);\n"
                    + "    //note evt.target can be a nested element, not the body element, resulting in misfires\n"
                    + "    var t = evt.target;\n"
                    + "    alert(t;\n"
                    + "});");`
```

i want to get alerted value 't' to Java String. like :

```
String ele = t;
```

Comment: I would consider inserting your own ID'd element containing "t" and then get the innerHTML.  It'll be easier to get at since Unexpected Alert Behavior is a little odd for certain drivers right now.

Comment: @pcalkins i tried to add new div with id ="t" like this : 
`   + "    document.body.innerHTML += '<div id = \"t\" style=\"display:none\">t</div>';    });"); ` but it is printing t as it is . i mean it is not printing value of "t" inside div

Comment: you don't need to set the ID to t... just use something you reference in Selenium later... for the other t var, just close quotes, use +, and open again... like ..."<div id = 'var_for_selenium'>" + t + "</div>"  You may want to build the string first for convenience.  Then executeScript the string var.  (For dealing with quotes...)

Comment: you might want to consider the purpose of this... Selenium will throw an exception if another element is going to retrieve the click so you could catch that kind of thing right there.

Comment: @pcalkins i will try out and will let you know , i am sorry for late ack.